# What does "" mean in python?

Tags: python

What does "" mean in python?

For example:

```
def makePassword(length) :
   password = ""
```

What does password become and/or what does that statement mean?
Does it redefine password? Does it just reemphasize the fact that password has already been defined above (assuming it has been). FYI: This is only part of a code.

Comment: Have you come across strings in python? Anything between two " is a sting as are some other things

Comment: It is an empty string.

Comment: It just means you are assigning an empty string to password. If password had any intial values then it will be override

Comment: as an aside, I tend to build empty containers using their constructor to make this more explicit (`password = str()`, `lst = list()`, `dct = dict()` etc)

Comment: There's some discussion about how best to create dictionaries, and list(), tuple() and str() are useful for conversions, but I've never seen anyone do that before. If you didn't want the empty string would you use `str("Initial value")`?

Comment: To stop the downvoting, you probably want to add the code to help us understand why you're asking 'Does it just reemphasize the fact that password has already been defined above (assuming it has been). FYI: This is only part of a code.'

Answer (score 2):

The

```
password = ""
```

sets `password` to the empty string (that is, the string consisting of zero characters).

It is worth noting that this is different to not assigning `password` anything at all (in which case it won't exist) and is different to setting password to [`None`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html).

Comment: How is a "string consisting of zero characters" introduced in a code?

Comment: @user3341166: by creating an empty string object; `''` or `""` or `''''''` or `""""""` are all empty string literals with 0 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Empty string (length 0). password becomes empty string.

> Does it redefine password?

It does, within the scope of that function. Or if password was declared as a global.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes exactly that, "". It's an 'empty' string essentially. It just becomes an object with type of string.

Answer (score 0):

In generating a string, sometimes results are created one character at a time, or in chunks. From the function name I suspect that this particular algorithm was doing something like that.

If the process is iterative (happens inside a loop) a natural way to add the latest chunk to whatever has already been accumulated is to use a statement such as

```
password = password + new_chunk
```

which can nowadays be written more concisely as

```
password += new_chunk
```

This takes the existing value of the `password` variable and adds the new chunk to it, replacing the old value of `password`.

Executing this statement without having assigned a value to the `password` variable would cause an exception, however (specifically you would see a NameError because the statement requires you to start with the existing value of `password`, and it doesn't have one). So before the loop you assign the null string (the one containing no characters) to the variable, thereby avoiding an inconvenient but all too common error.